# Mapping a nested collections using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, nested-object

I have been trying to map my entities to my viewmodels with AutoMapper. And faced problems with nested collection mapping.

The Source

```
public class Consignment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConsignmentLine> ConsignmentLines { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConsignmentDocument> ConsignmentDocuments { get; set; }
}

public class ConsignmentLine
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConsignmentDocument> ConsignmentDocuments { get; set; }
}

public class ConsignmentDocument
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public Guid ConsignmentLineId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
}

public class ConsignmentLineViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConsignmentDocumentViewModel> ConsignmentDocuments { get; set; }
}
 
public class ConsignmentDocumentViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public Guid ConsignmentLineId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }
}
```

The destination

```
public class ConsignmentDetailsViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConsignmentLineViewModel> ConsignmentLines { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConsignmentDocumentViewModel> ConsignmentDocuments { get; set; }
}
```

I can map consignmentDocuments for each consignment very easily but while mapping consignmentlines for each consignment i am getting an "AutoMapper Exception". I know the exception is being generated because of each consignmentLine has it's own collection of consignmentDocuments.

Right now my automapper profile

```
CreateMap<Consignment, ConsignmentDetailsViewModel>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.consignmentLineViewModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.ConsignmentLine.ToList()))
            .ForMember(vm => vm.consignmentDocumentViews, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.ConsignmentDocument.ToList()));
```

How can I map all of them to the ConsignmentViewModel class?

Comment: Can you show us the exception which you are getting, also you haven't include view models for consignment lines and consignment documents.

Comment: @Muhammad this is the exception i am getting "Exception thrown: 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' in AutoMapper.dll"

Comment: also I added consignmentLineViewModel and ConsignmentDocumentViewModel

Comment: Also can you post the code which you are trying to map from source to destination

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem.

The solution is to create a map for ConsignmentLine to get the collection of ConsignmentDocuments.

```
CreateMap<Consignment, ConsignmentDetailsViewModel>()
        .ForMember(vm => vm.consignmentLineViewModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.ConsignmentLine))
        .ForMember(vm => vm.consignmentDocumentViews, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.ConsignmentDocument));

CreateMap<ConsignmentLine, ConsignmentLineViewModel>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.consignmentDocumentViews, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.ConsignmentDocument));
```

Comment: You don't need `ToList`.

Answer (score 0):

If you act simply without thinking too complex in AutoMapper transactions, you can perform all your transactions.

Example:

```
 CreateMap<Consignment, ConsignmentDetailsViewModel>();
 CreateMap<ConsignmentLine, ConsignmentLineViewModel>();
 CreateMap<ConsignmentDocument, ConsignmentDocumentViewModel>();
```